# how to open excel on foreground in VBA using powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

i am trying to open an excel file in a powerpoint presentation.
this is my code:

```
Sub diversestickersKoole()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("V:\Oliedocs\Koole\Stickers Scheepstanks Koole.xltm", True, False)

Set xlApp = Nothing    
Set xlWorkBook = Nothing
End Sub
```

the excel file is opening in the background. this must be in the foreground.

can someone help me?

Comment: Shouldn't it be End Sub instead of End Function? The code opens the workbook on top of the presentation. What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line xlWorkBook.Activate should be enough.

Your code should look like this:

```
Sub diversestickersKoole()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("V:\Oliedocs\Koole\Stickers   Scheepstanks Koole.xltm", True, False)

xlWorkBook.Activate

Set xlApp = Nothing

Set xlWorkBook = Nothing


End Function
```

For references:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/670476-excel-visual-basic-applications-test-if-workbook-open-if-so-bring-front.html

Post #4

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AppActivate`.

The code below uses *"test.xlsx - Excel* as this is the caption of my test workbook.

*Stickers Scheepstanks Koole.xltm - Excel* should work for you

```
Sub diversestickersKoole()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Visible = True
'Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("V:\Oliedocs\Koole\Stickers Scheepstanks Koole.xltm", True, False)
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\test.xlsx", True, False)
AppActivate "test.xlsx - Excel"

Set xlApp = Nothing

Set xlWorkBook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

since you seem not interested in keeping Excel object and its derived ones , you may want to code like follows

```
Sub diversestickersKoole()
    With CreateObject("Excel.Application") '<--| create a new Excel instance and reference it (all its derived objects will be reached by a 'dot')
        .Visible = True 
        .WindowState = -4137 '<--| maximize Excel window
        .Workbooks.Open("V:\Oliedocs\Koole\Stickers Scheepstanks Koole.xltm", True, False).Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work, the excel file is opened in the background.